# How to make 1km x 1km grid in R using .shp file(Korea, Seoul)?

Tags: r, grid, gis

I recently studied R to have to make the 1km x 1km grid. So, I already have done below the code. But the `shapefile(korea, seoul and WGS84)` accurately could't added(or overlayed) to grid.
So, I need your help to fix this problems.

1. shapefile has CRS like this
   `+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84+towgs84=0,0,0`
2. To make 1km x 1km resolution of grid, I've been using spTransform function like below code.
   `seoullayer_t <- spTransform(seoullayer, CRS("+init=epsg:3857"))`
3. To ensure the origin of grid

   ```
   x <- min(coordinates(seoullyaer_t)[,1]) ; x
   y <- min(coordinates(seoullyaer_t)[,2]) ; y
   ```

   BUT, the shpaefile and gird(raster) doesn't be matched exactly.
   How could be fixed this problems...

```
    seoullayer <- rgdal :: readOGR(dsn = 'd:/seoullayer',
                               layer = 'test_4326',
                               encoding = 'CP949')

    seoullayer_t <- spTransform(seoullayer, CRS("+init=epsg:3857"))

    # Define number of cells of Grid
    x <- min(coordinates(seoullyaer_t)[,1]) ; x
    y <- min(coordinates(seoullyaer_t)[,2]) ; y

    x_cell <- 46
    y_cell <- 37

    cell_size <- 1000
    ext <- extent(x, x + (x_cell * cell_size), y, y + (y_cell * cell_size))
    ras <- raster(ext)

    #Set the resolution to be
    res(ras) <- c(cell_size, cell_size)
    ras[] <- rnorm(ncell(ras))
    projection(ras) <- CRS("+init=epsg:3857")

    plot(ras)
    plot(seoullayer_t, add = T)
```

I hope that I make the gird resolution 1km x 1km and put the values(like temp, density of PM10, O3 etc) in the grid. So, finally I want to do "inverse distance wieghting method" to predict the values which doesn't have actual values.

Please help me to do like that. Thanks.

Comment: the actual value of east~west / north~south length : 36.78km /30.3km. But as I convert ESPG : 4326 to ESPG : 3857, the values of east~west and north~south are not same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like

```
library(raster)
g <- getData("GADM", country="South Korea", level=1)
m <- spTransform(g, "+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +units=m")
r <- raster(m, res=10000)
```

However, your choice of coordinate reference system (mercator) is not a good one, as it is not an equal-area projection. Also note that it is better to write out a "proj.4" description than to use a EPSG code, because these codes are opaque (you cannot see the relevant information). I do not know what a good crs is for South Korea but you can look that up. UTM might be reasonable.

```
m <- spTransform(g, "+proj=utm +zone=52 +datum=WGS84")
r <- raster(floor(extent(m)), res=10000)
```

(I round the extent to get whole numbers).